# Proper quoting of `curl -H`

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, macos

Using `curl -H` I am seeing inconsistent results when attempting to quote for the first header but not the second. My curl command is turning double quotes into single quotes for the second header command but appears to be stripping all quotes for the first `-H` command. Is there some behind-the-scenes logic that `curl` is using here? I don't see any mention of this in `man curl`.

My shell is `zsh` and I have `set -x` for debugging mode to see the results of the commands.

It appears that using single quotes for the first -H command "invisibly" single quotes. The command runs without error.

**command with single quotes**

```sh
curl -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted' -H "accept: application/json" ${ENDPOINT}${query}${PARAM}
```

**result**

```sh
curl -H Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted -H 'accept: application/json' '{https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search\?q=}{star+wars+1977}{+site:imdb.com/title\&count=1\&offset=0\&responseFilter=webPages}'
```

It appears that using double quotes for the first -H command "invisibly" single quotes. The command runs without error.

**command with double quotes**

```sh
curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted" -H "accept: application/json" ${ENDPOINT}${query}${PARAM}
```

**result**

```sh
curl -H Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted -H 'accept: application/json' '{https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search\?q=}{star+wars+1977}{+site:imdb.com/title\&count=1\&offset=0\&responseFilter=webPages}'
```

The following commands all fail. Looking at the output I see strange results from escaping.

**command with escaped double quotes**

```sh
curl -H \"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted\" -H "accept: application/json" ${ENDPOINT}${query}${PARAM}
```

**result**

```sh
curl -H '"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted"' -H 'accept: application/json' '{https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search\?q=}{star+wars+1977}{+site:imdb.com/title\&count=1\&offset=0\&responseFilter=webPages}'
```

**command with escaped single quotes**

```sh
curl -H \'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted\' -H "accept: application/json" ${ENDPOINT}${query}${PARAM}
```

**result**

```sh
curl -H \''Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:redacted'\' -H 'accept: application/json' '{https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search\?q=}{star+wars+1977}{+site:imdb.com/title\&count=1\&offset=0\&responseFilter=webPages}'
```

Comment: Quoting is handled by the shell, not  the command you try to run. Which problem are you trying to solve with quoting here?

Comment: I am trying to understand the inconsistency in the results when quoting the two `curl -H` commands on the same line. Look at the second example.

Comment: How do you create the results, where do you copy them from?

Comment: The results are from the shell (zsh) while using `set -x`.

Comment: @John What you are seeing is just an artifact of how `set -x` reports commands. It parses the command, figures out what the command and its arguments are, then works backward to figure out *something that would produce that command and arguments*. In other words, what it prints is not the command you entered, but it's effectively equivalent to it. If an argument didn't really need quoting, it doesn't quote it. If it has at least one weird character in it, it puts single-quotes around it (and if there are actual single-quotes in the arg, it gets a little silly).

Comment: See the Unix & Linux question ["Why does bash add single quotes to unquoted failed pathname expansions in a command before executing it?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118403/why-does-bash-add-single-quotes-to-unquoted-failed-pathname-expansions-in-a-comm/118466#118466)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you! That was driving me nuts. Do you know of a way to get what command was actually sent or output in this instance?

Comment: With sent you mean used by curl? Curl doesn‘t see any of the quotes (unless they are escaped), their sole purpose is to prevent the shell from breaking arguments containing spaces and similar stuff.

Comment: What the command was actually sent is a series of separate strings (passed as separate arguments to an `execl*()` family function, or as an array to an `execv*()` function). To print them, you'd need to add some sort of delimiter to indicate where one ends and the next begins... and if that delimiter occurs in one of the arguments, you need a way to indicate it's part of the argument and not acting as a delimiter, and .... etc. That's exactly what `set -x` does, using space as the delimiter, and single-quotes to indicate that spaces are part of args, not delimiters.